# Ideas about clearing a clogged collection ball on conical fermenter

Tags: yeast, techniques, secondary-fermentation

I am preparing a heavily dry hopped beer.  So far I have added my home grown yeast on brewing day with multiple hops.  I have dry hopped twice again, and am at the final dry hop 5 days before bottling.  I emptied the collection ball once with no problem, but when I tried to empty it again it was clogged with hops and yeast.  Put on a empty collection ball and opened it but after 4 days still not unclogged (thought the gravity and pressure would loosen).  Any suggestions without having to obtain a large sanitized object to poke holes in the clog from above.  The clog is actually in the bottom of the fermenter where the collection drains into the ball.

Comment: Hence why heavy dry hopping is often done in a secondary fermentation vessel. If you have to dry hop in primary or the conical vessel then I recommend using a nylon containment bag - even if it is a large one!

Comment: I have decided you are correct.  I use the conical fermenter to avoid contamination, but ended up having to open it 5 times in fermentation.  Sad thing is, I have nylon bags in my brew drawer.  Thanks, Pete, I live and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe swirling the conical if it's small enough?

Aside from that really the only way is to attach a gas fitting to the collection valve in place of the bulb and shoot some cO2 up there to burb the hop trub up from the bottom.

Comment: thanks, I finally did get it loose, but have decided the best answer is not to clog the collection ball in the first place.  Mine was just a newbie mistake.